# Executing a dtsx file from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a SSIS package in SQL Server 2005 that I want to execute from a stored procedure or trigger on a table insert or update.

How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A couple of options are:

- Run the package by calling [dtexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) from the stored procedure
- Write a [CLR procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790.aspx) that uses the [SSIS object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx) to run the package
- Create a SQL Agent job that runs the package and run the job using the [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) stored procedure

See the following articles for further explanations

- [Running SSIS Package Programatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx).
- [How to Call SSIS Package from the Stored Procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27156/How-to-Call-SSIS-Package-from-the-Stored-Procedure)
- [Execute SSIS Package from Stored Procedure with Parameters using DTEXEC Utility](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/24/execute-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-with-parameters-using-dtexec-utility.aspx)

Comment: I don't recommend using dtexec from the stored procedure as that requires using xp_cmdshell, which is not the most secure method and also may be locked down by your DBA.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an unscheduled SQL Agent job that is configured to run the SSIS package. Then from your stored procedure or trigger, use sp_startjob to run the job.

sp_start_job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx