# SSIS : Executing local dtsx package without using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime in .NET 6 with SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, smo

I am working on upgrading C# web service from .net 4.5 to .NET 6.

There is no / could not find replacement for Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime in .net core or .NET 6. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3747.
I cant directly import it in NET 6 application as application will not be platform independent then.  Please let me know if there are any other ways to still use "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime" in NET6.

Existing code loads and runs the local .dtsx package from bin folder of application programmatically using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-local-package-programmatically?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Part of the code is

```
  string pkgLocation;  
  Package pkg;  
  Application app;  
  DTSExecResult pkgResults;  
  
  //package present in bin folder
  pkgLocation =  Path.Combine(assemblyExecutingPath, @"bin\Packages\Pkg.dtsx");
  
  var eventListener = new SsisEventListener();

  //Load local package
  app = new Application();  
  pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener );
 
  pkg.Variables["USER::SourceConnectionString"].Value = connectionstring  //Connectionstring with SSIP and sqlni provider

  //Execute 
  pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null,Variable, pkg.eventListener,null,null );
```

As `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime` is not available in .NET 6, I am looking for other options to execute LOCAL `.dtsx` packages. Looking into T-SQL option I found this:

[Executing a dtsx file from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245051/executing-a-dtsx-file-from-a-stored-procedure)

where following options are mentioned

1. Run the package by calling `dtexec` from the stored procedure
   query => it runs in SQL Server, so it will not be useful for executing local `.dtsx` packages? As that requires using `xp_cmdshell`, which is not the most secure method?
2. Write a CLR procedure that uses the SSIS object model to run the package

   Query/Problem => useful for executing local dtsx packages? SSIS object model not compatible with .NET 6
3. Create a SQL Server Agent job that runs the package and run the job using the sp_start_job stored procedure

   Query/Problem => need more information.

If there is any other way to execute local `.dtsx` packages, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no local SSIS packages. It is a misnomer. SSIS is a server side product, part of MS SQL Server that needs to be installed. And you need a license for that.

Comment: See if following works : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks jdweng.  but  references mentioned in above link (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc,Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) are not available for .NET Core

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky yes, package runs on MS SQL server but as per existing code, location of .DTSX package is bin folder of web service, its gets loaded and then executed, so I used "Local" word to denote location for package.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-05-23, SSIS works with the .NET Framework and that's it. Core, Standard, Diet or any other variation they come up with in the future don't support it.

Your options for running an SSIS Package are

- .NET Framework libraries
- CLR stored procedures that run SSIS packages in the SSISDB, which under the covers use the .NET Framework Libraries
- DTEXEC.exe, 32 or 64 bit variant, which under the covers use .NET Framework Libraries

Comment: Thanks @billinkc. So no deployment platform independence  for SSIS in any of above option?

Comment: Not sure I quite grok "deployment platform independence" but SSIS is a tool that is licensed/bound to SQL Server. It's a nifty tool for moving data but it's not "free." When you run an SSIS package from Visual Studio, the command line or via the libraries, it performs a licensing check. Until the team makes SQL Server and then the associated tooling work with .NET Core. Or the .NET teams makes a way to leverage Framework libraries I don't see how a person can modernize running packages.